# Command-line tool which replaces .manifest file

Tags: delphi, manifest

This will be short: Is there any command line tool to replace .manifest file in application?

// Edit:
I mean in resources of EXE.

Comment: Maybe too short for me!? Shouldn't `copy application.new.manifest application.old.manifest` do it?

Comment: I edited my question. I mean the replace in EXE (resources).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line tool is brcc32.exe which comes with Delphi. Supposing your manifest is in the file named `manifest.xml`:

1) Create file `manifest.rc` with the following contents:

```
1     24     manifest.xml
```

2) Compile the .rc file with brcc32

3) Add the resulting .res file to your .dpr file:

```
{$R manifest.res}
```

Alternatively, instead of steps 2) and 3) just add the .rc file to your .dpr file:

```
{$R 'manifest.res' 'manifest.rc'}
```

This will include compiling the resource in the IDE build process so you don't have to invoke brcc32 manually.

Note: Also disable "Enable runtime themes" in Project Options since that would replace your explicit manifest resource. Instead, include the [appropriate Common Controls declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwtazz9d(VS.80).aspx) in your own manifest.

Comment: This technically is part of the build process so you're not actually replacing any resource in an existing executable...

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of command line tools to do it, though you could knock your own up pretty easy using the resource API's, there's definately calls to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a command-line tool to modify resources: ResHacker.
http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/